# nodejs multer uable to create directory and upload files

Tags: node.js, multer

I have used middleware - upload which returns error after giving both received files in log:
Error:  `ENOENT no such file or directory open, C:\{path here}`

uploaddata.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const multer  =  require("multer");
/* const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.static(__dirname+"uploads/")); */


const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {    
    console.log("file.fieldname", file);  
      callback(null, 'uploads/'+file.fieldname+'/');  
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    console.log("filename::", file.originalname);    
      callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);    
  }
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: Storage,
  limits: {
      fileSize: 1024 * 1024 
  },
  fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      checkFileType(file, cb);
  }
}).fields(
  [
      {
      name:'userpic',
      maxCount:1
      },
      {
      name:'usercv',
      maxCount:1
      }
  ]
);

function checkFileType(file, cb) {    
//  console.log("file.fieldname", file);
    if(file.fieldname==="userpic")
    {
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/png' || file.mimetype === 'image/jpg' ||  file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg')
         { // check file type to be png, jpeg, or jpg
            cb(null, true);
          } else {
            cb(null, false); // else fails
          }
    }
    if(file.fieldname==="usercv")
    {
     if ( file.mimetype === 'application/pdf' || file.mimetype === 'application/msword' ||  file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' )
      { // check file type to be pdf, doc, or docx
            cb(null, true);
          } else {
            cb(null, false); // else fails
          }
    }
  }
    
    module.exports = upload;
```

in console via postman I am sending image and docx file which is reading successfully but it unable to create directory and those files on server path
can any one gives me solution..

Comment: make sure you are pointing to an existing dir, otherwise you need to create that dir

Comment: can you explain how should i create directory dynamically.
Does multer destination should create directory??

Comment: multer does not create DIR for you automatically, you can use npm package like https://www.npmjs.com/package/make-dir . another option is to just use `import fs from 'fs' `

Comment: const makeDir = require('make-dir');

const Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, callback) {    
    console.log("file.fieldname", file); 
    (async () => {     
    const dir = await makeDir('uploads/'+file.fieldname+'/');   
      console.log(dir);
      callback(null, dir);
    })();
      //=> '/Users/sindresorhus/fun/unicorn/rainbow/cake'
        
  },
  filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    console.log("filename::", file.originalname);    
      callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);    
  }
});

Comment: above code worked...

Comment: That's good to know that I've helped somehow